# How to get key-value pairs from servlet in java script using ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, json, servlets

In my servlet I am creating a list key-value pairs with the help of a Map

```
Map map=new HashMap();  
map.put("1", "john");  
map.put("2", "cris");  
map.put("3","patrik");  
JSONObject jsonMap=new JSONObject(map);  

out.print(jsonMap);
```

I am calling the above servlet through ajax. 
I want to know how can I print all the key-value pairs in my javascript(**with and without using jquery**) without knowing the key values?

Any other idea how can I get both key-value pairs from servlet in javascript using ajax ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though not safe, you can use [`eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) to convert this response to a JSON object on the javascript side as follows:

```
eval("var json = " + xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
for (var i in json) {
    // i and json[i] are the key and values respectively.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the javascript arrays if you don't know the key.
i.e.

```
var resp = JSON.parse(responseText);
for(i=0; i<resp.length;i++){
    console.log(resp[i]);
}
```